# Format intersection of groups with index below intersection symbol

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I'm writing in LyX and would like to format the intersection of groups such that the index appears directly below a large U.  Currently I do the following which produces a relatively small U with the index as a subscript kind of off to the right a bit:  `$\cap_{2\leq n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$`

Answer (score 6):

The correct command to use is `\bigcap` that takes limits in display math mode. Not in in-line math mode, for typographical reasons. So

```
\[
\bigcap_{2\leq n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}
\]
```

will place the limits below the symbol, while the same input in $...$ won't (but it's the desired behavior, trust me).

Comment: You can get it inline as well by using `\limits`. You would do that as follows: `$\bigcap\limits_{2\leq n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}$`. However, this won't look good at all in running text, so I suggest you follow egreg's advice and use display mode.

Comment: I'm completely new to latex and LyX, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say display mode and in-line mode.  When I input a math formula I usually hit ctrl-m and type in the latex commands.  Could you explain a little more in detail how I get this in LyX?